# Jquery :not selector with wildcard

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a simple onclick function that hides divs with the same loop number as the link. I'm hitting my head against a brick wall trying to get a not selector working.

In pseudo, i want all divs with the class starting "title" EXCEPT the current one to go to 0px in height.

```
$('div.[class^="title"]:not([class='title<?php echo $count;?>'])').css('height', '0px');
```

$count is the current loop.

This is the line i've managed to create. Is this syntax correct?

Comment: Does your element have multiple classes on it? Are you sure this specific class will always be the "first" one in the className list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIXED! After hours of trying to get this code to work, i came to realise (not long before @Tushar ) That the problem was that i was using multiple classes. I changed the "title" to the ID. Now everythings working perfectly.

Thank you everyone for your help.

final code looked like this:

```
$('#title<?php echo $count; ?>').animate({ opacity: "1", height: "300px" },{queue: false, duration: 200} );
                                $('div[id^="title"]').not('div[id$="title<?php echo $count; ?>"]').css('opacity', '0');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('div.[class^="title"]:not([class="title<?php echo $count;?>"])').css('height', '0px');
//Changed single to double quote   ^                         ^
```

Comment: No luck. But my onclick started animating it'self to show. So that's a good sign. hmm.... The full code for this wp function is:

Comment: `jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.title<?php echo $count; ?>').click(function() {
      
$('div.title<?php echo $count; ?>').animate({ opacity: "1" },{queue: false, duration: 200} )
.animate({ height: "300px" }, 200 );
$('div.[class^="title"]:not([class="title<?php echo $count;?>"])').css('height', '0px');
$('div.[class^="title"]:not([class="title<?php echo $count;?>"])').css('opacity', '0');
});
});
});`

Comment: @DanielRuxton what is not working  ? Do you get any error on console ?

Comment: There isn't an error in the console. I've tried switching it around, so that on the click it hides things first before showing the animation... but i'm still having no luck showing the code with the wildcard.

Comment: @DanielRuxton Try  `console.log("<?php echo $count;?>");` inside click event and also `console.log(this)`.

Comment: the number is definately appearing. I checked the script on thepage and the correct title number is showing.

Comment: @DanielRuxton Try change `$('a.title<?php echo $count; ?>')` to `$("a.title<?php echo $count; ?>")`. I think you need double quotes to get php variable.

Comment: As i said above, the php variable is most certainly appearing. http://puu.sh/5feLd.png. On click it's setting the opacity and height of what's b eing clicked... however it's not setting everything else to 0 opacity and height.

Comment: @DanielRuxton show your JavaScript code image which is Outputted in Browser .

Comment: Sorry, this is the full code working here. i had the opacity removed while i was checking it. http://puu.sh/5ffsN.png

Comment: @DanielRuxton Does the height change to `0` ?

Comment: it doesn't. nor does the opacity.

Comment: @DanielRuxton do you have team viewer ?

Comment: I do, however i'd rather not use it. We can move this discussion to chat if you would like however. Puush is just as viable.

Comment: @DanielRuxton can you put all your generated html,jQuery into fiddle .

Comment: @DanielRuxton i need generated html too in the fiddle .

Comment: that's it updated. The problem is that jsfiddle doesn't loop WP correctly.. so i can't really show the loop correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error at your code. You should use double quote instead of single quote at your Javascript. So the correct one is that you use:

```
$('div.[class^="title"]:not([class="title<?php echo $count;?>"])').css('height', '0px');
```

I think if you try that, it should just work!

Comment: No luck at all i'm afraid. unrecognized expression apparently. At least yours came up on the console. HAhaha.